# R (OSX) read/write xls

Tags: excel, r, xls

I'm having a persistant problem finding and implementing any packages capable of reading and writing XLS files in an OSX version of R.

Anyone have any suggestions?

I've gone so far as to try using Perl to implement WriteXls.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I have had success with the Java based `xlsx` package. Available on CRAN. It does .xls as well as .xlsx.

Answer (score 3):

`read.xls` in package gdata has worked for me in the past. You can get some [further tips at the wiki page](http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=tips%3adata-io%3ams_windows&s=excel).

Answer (score 3):

Another package to try is `XLConnect`.